# Unexpected result from transformer model prediction

Tags: python, pandas, huggingface-transformers

Working with huggingface transformers for Masked Language Task I have expected that prediction will return the same input string plus tokens for masked ones:

```
from transformers import BertConfig, BertTokenizer, BertForMaskedLM

model1 = BertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
tokenizer1 = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")

# Read the rest of this [MASK] to understand things in more detail
text = ["Read the rest of this [MASK] to understand things in more detail"]
encoding1 = tokenizer1(text, return_tensors="pt")

# forward pass
outputs1 = model1(**encoding1)
outputs1.logits.argmax(-1)
```

The output is :

```
tensor([[1012, 3191, 1996, 2717, 1997, 2023, 2338, 2000, 3305, 2477, 1999, 2062,
         1012, 1012]])
```

But when I have decoded the output I did not find last input token ***detail*** :

```
tokenizer1.convert_ids_to_tokens([1012, 3191, 1996, 2717, 1997, 2023, 2338, 2000, 3305, 2477, 1999, 2062, 1012, 1012])


['.',
 'read',
 'the',
 'rest',
 'of',
 'this',
 'book',
 'to',
 'understand',
 'things',
 'in',
 'more',
 '.',
 '.']
```

Maybe I'm using it incorrectly model? Any other reason?

Answer (score 0):

I would attribute this simply to a mistake by the neural network. While BERT is very good at predicting most samples, it could still happen that individual tokens are incorrectly predicted.
Further, it is important to note that BERT is incapable of adding/removing tokens, i.e., the output **must** always be the same length as the input (in terms of BPE units).

Interestingly, I tried adding a period to the end of your example sentence, i.e.

```py
# Adding period
text = ["Read the rest of this [MASK] to understand things in more detail."]
```

and the output is now "more correct":

```py
'. read the rest of this book to understand things in more detail..'
```

So it seems BERT learns that a sentence *always* has to end in a period, which supersedes the correct prediciton of `detail`. Note that the `[CLS]` and `[SEP]` tokens (at the very beginning and end) also get converted to periods as well, but that is likely due to a similar interpretation.